# After restoring my iPhone from iCloud, my photos are all low resolution. How can I fix this?

Tags: ios, icloud, iphone, photos.app

I restored my iPhone 4S from iCloud after recieving a replacement one from the Apple store. It took many hours for The applications and photos to come back but once restored, all of the photos on the iPhone are now low resolution.

How can I restore the photos, which were backed up to iCloud, back to my iPhone in their original resolution?

Comment: Are you sure the photos were backed up to iCloud and it wasn't just Photo Stream that was enabled?

Comment: The restoration process restored all of the thumbnails and looked like it had restored everything but on clicking the thumbnail only a low resolution photo is displayed.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this site](http://www.iosphotoapps.com/2011/12/28/icloud-photo-stream-whats-right-whats-wrong/) it is a limitation of iCloud. You can, however, download the full-resolution images from iCloud to your computer. So you haven't lost the high-res versions, you just have to pull them over through local syncing and not iCloud.